# Downloading data from webpage (yahoo finance) that is not a csv

Tags: python, stock-data

I would like to download the float data that is on Yahoo Finance for multiple stocks at the same time, but I have no idea how to code this.

I am a little familiar with python and because of Stackoverflow I have been able to download .csv historical prices, but now I also would like to download the float of the stock.

Could anyone help me with the issue?

the url link is

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=AAPL

Comment: What have you tried? These links may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49705047/downloading-mutliple-stocks-at-once-from-yahoo-finance-python , https://pypi.org/project/yahoo-finance/ and https://www.learndatasci.com/tutorials/python-finance-part-yahoo-finance-api-pandas-matplotlib/

Comment: Currently I have been using Excel to do this but it is really slow.

Comment: Right now I am trying to do it by using python and a different web adres.

I have some progress but I am unable to receive the data in python, i might have to make a new post though because the title is not relevant anymore.

Comment: import requests

url = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/stats"

json_data = requests.get(url).json

print(json_data)

Comment: is the code I am currently using

Comment: saveFile = open('Float Data.txt', 'a+')
saveFile.write(text_lines)
saveFile.close()

Comment: You should put all this in your question above. Just use edit button. Then delete all these comments.