# "TypeError: string indices must be integers" when getting data of a stock from Yahoo Finance using Pandas Datareader

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

```
import pandas_datareader

end = "2022-12-15"
start = "2022-12-15"
stock_list = ["TATAELXSI.NS"]

data = pandas_datareader.get_data_yahoo(symbols=stock_list, start=start, end=end)

print(data)
```

When I run this code, I get error `"TypeError: string indices must be integers"`.

Edit : I have updated the code and passed list as symbol parameter but it still shows the same error

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Deepak Shetter\PycharmProjects\100DAYSOFPYTHON\mp3downloader.py", line 7, in <module>
    data = pandas_datareader.get_data_yahoo(symbols=[TATAELXSI], start=start, end=end)
  File "C:\Users\Deepak Shetter\PycharmProjects\100DAYSOFPYTHON\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 80, in get_data_yahoo
    return YahooDailyReader(*args, **kwargs).read()
  File "C:\Users\Deepak Shetter\PycharmProjects\100DAYSOFPYTHON\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 258, in read
    df = self._dl_mult_symbols(self.symbols)
  File "C:\Users\Deepak Shetter\PycharmProjects\100DAYSOFPYTHON\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 268, in _dl_mult_symbols
    stocks[sym] = self._read_one_data(self.url, self._get_params(sym))
  File "C:\Users\Deepak Shetter\PycharmProjects\100DAYSOFPYTHON\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py", line 153, in _read_one_data
    data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: has it only been recent? was it happening even before?

Comment: I would suggest to use yfinance in the meanwhile..

Comment: @NikhilMulley It happened just today(Saturday , dec 16). Was working fine yesterday.

Comment: It started happening to me today too. No changes to the code that yesterday was working fine.

Comment: I am discovering it just now, but indeed, failing for me too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

None of the solutions reported here so far worked for me. As per the discussion [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/952) Yahoo made changes to their API that broke compatibility with previous pandas datareader versions.

In the same Github thread a fix is reported, implemented in a pull request from Github user raphi6. I confirmed the pull request works fine. The version from the pull request can be installed with this 3 lines:

```
conda install pycryptodome pycryptodomex
conda uninstall pandas-datareader
pip install git+https://github.com/raphi6/pandas-datareader.git@ea66d6b981554f9d0262038aef2106dda7138316
```

The `pycrypto*` packages are dependencies I have to install to make it work. Notice I am using the commit hash here instead of the branch name, because it is `Yahoo!_Issue#952` and there is an [issue with hash characters](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10226) when using pip this way.

This can also be done using pip for all the commands instead of conda (see Update 1 below).

**Update 1**

To try this on Google Colab use (as shown [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/952#issuecomment-1358980542)):

```
! pip install pycryptodome pycryptodomex
! pip uninstall --yes pandas-datareader
! pip install git+https://github.com/raphi6/pandas-datareader.git@ea66d6b981554f9d0262038aef2106dda7138316
```

**Update 2** (27/12/2022)

Although past week I could not make it work, I have tried again, and I can confirm that the `pdr_override()` workaround mentioned below by Nikhil Mulley is working now (at least with yfinance 0.2.3 and pandas-datareader 0.10.0).

**Original answer (works but more lines of code)**

In the same Github thread a fix is reported, implemented in a pull request from Github user raphi6. I confirmed the pull request works fine. Detailed installation instructions for the pull request can be found [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/952#issuecomment-1357975945), copied below for the sake of completeness:

```
git clone https://github.com/raphi6/pandas-datareader.git
cd pandas-datareader
conda uninstall pandas-datareader
conda install pycryptodome pycryptodomex
git checkout 'Yahoo!_Issue#952'
python setup.py install --record installed_files.txt
```

The `--record` argument in the install command is to get a list of installed files, so that it is easy to uninstall in the future (following [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall)). The `pycrypto*` files are dependencies I have to install to make it work.

Comment: Is it possible to implement this in google colab?

Comment: Not sure about this working in google colab. I've tried installing it using this `! git clone https://github.com/raphi6/pandas-datareader.git
&& cd pandas-datareader && git checkout 'Yahoo!_Issue#952' && pip uninstall --yes pandas-datareader && yes | pip install pycryptodome pycryptodomex && python setup.py install --record installed_files.txt`. Command seems to work fine in google colab, but then `import pandas_datareader` failed with a module not found error. Any clue?

Comment: The [updated issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/952#issuecomment-1358980542) in Github shows how to do it in Google Colab. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Updated answer with a more elegant solution using pip instead of `setup.py`, also friendlier with Google Colab.

Comment: I've executed the Update 2 shell commands, but am getting a different error `Padding is incorrect.` Seems strange that in 2024 we would be getting the same error listed above.

Answer (score 19):

My solution is simple, I just replace the pandas_datareader.get_data_yahoo with yf.download. And needless to worry about the result, because yf.download will also give you a dataframe. I simplify my syntax as below:

```
import yfinance as yf

df = yf.download(your_ticks_or_a_tick_list, start=start_date, end=end_date)
```

But please remember to Clear Outputs of All Cells, and Restart or you will get an error.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me as of Jul/2023

Comment: Superior answer

Answer (score 14):

This is not an answer, but I think the problem is related with pdr data reader fetching from yahoo itself

```
>>> import pandas_datareader as dtr
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> initial_portfolio=['AAPL', 'MA', 'F', 'MSFT', '^GSPC']
>>> startdate = datetime(2022,12,1)
>>> enddate=datetime(2022,12,10)
>>> stock_data=dtr.yahoo.daily.YahooDailyReader(initial_portfolio,start=startdate,end=enddate).read()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 258, in read
    df = self._dl_mult_symbols(self.symbols)
  File "lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 268, in _dl_mult_symbols
    stocks[sym] = self._read_one_data(self.url, self._get_params(sym))
  File "lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py", line 153, in _read_one_data
    data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

and the **short term fix** could be to use yfinance override and see if that helps in the meanwhile until yahoo finance restores their data functionality?

```
Python 3.9.1 (default, Dec 28 2020, 11:22:14)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
>>> import yfinance as yf
>>> yf.pdr_override()
>>> y_symbols = ['SCHAND.NS', 'TATAPOWER.NS', 'ITC.NS']
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> startdate = datetime(2022,12,1)
>>> enddate = datetime(2022,12,15)
>>> data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(y_symbols, start=startdate, end=enddate)
[*********************100%***********************]  3 of 3 completed
>>> data
             Adj Close                                Close                           ...        Open                             Volume
                ITC.NS   SCHAND.NS TATAPOWER.NS      ITC.NS   SCHAND.NS TATAPOWER.NS  ...      ITC.NS   SCHAND.NS TATAPOWER.NS    ITC.NS SCHAND.NS TATAPOWER.NS
Date                                                                                  ...
2022-12-01  339.549988  195.949997   224.850006  339.549988  195.949997   224.850006  ...  341.700012  191.600006   225.250000  16630417    544485      7833074
2022-12-02  337.149994  196.600006   225.250000  337.149994  196.600006   225.250000  ...  339.350006  196.000000   225.449997   8388835    122126      7223274
2022-12-05  336.750000  191.050003   224.199997  336.750000  191.050003   224.199997  ...  337.649994  200.850006   225.250000   9716390    107294     10750610
2022-12-06  337.299988  196.399994   228.800003  337.299988  196.399994   228.800003  ...  334.100006  191.000000   224.199997   6327430    102911     20071039
2022-12-07  340.100006  187.350006   225.850006  340.100006  187.350006   225.850006  ...  338.500000  198.000000   228.800003   9813208    122772      7548312
2022-12-08  338.399994  181.850006   225.050003  338.399994  181.850006   225.050003  ...  340.200012  186.000000   226.000000   6200447    114147      7507975
2022-12-09  341.399994  176.899994   219.399994  341.399994  176.899994   219.399994  ...  339.750000  183.899994   225.899994   8132228    179660     13087278
2022-12-12  343.200012  177.350006   217.699997  343.200012  177.350006   217.699997  ...  341.000000  177.750000   219.750000  11214662    133507      8858525
2022-12-13  345.600006  178.449997   218.850006  345.600006  178.449997   218.850006  ...  344.500000  179.350006   218.800003  10693426     74873      7265105
2022-12-14  345.399994  179.149994   222.699997  345.399994  179.149994   222.699997  ...  346.000000  180.449997   219.800003   7379878     32085      9179593

[10 rows x 18 columns]
>>>
```

Answer (score 10):

Use yahoo finance instead, it worked for me:

```
import datetime as dt
import yfinance as yf

company = 'TATAELXSI.NS'

# Define a start date and End Date
start = dt.datetime(2020,1,1)
end =  dt.datetime(2022,1,1)

# Read Stock Price Data 
data = yf.download(company, start , end)

data.tail(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

the solution that worked for me in 09/25/2023

i replace

```
import pandas_datareader as web
web.DataReader('AMZN', 'yahoo', start, end)
```

with

```
import yfinance 
yfinance.download('AMZN', start, end)
```