# Pandas Datareader is not working as it used to be

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I've been using Pandas Datareader for a while to extract stock prices. I've been using the exact same function that I included below for a while and it always worked perfectly fine. For some reason, however, when I ran the same exact function today, I get an error message saying,

"line 9, in 
df = web.DataReader(ticker, source, start, end)
...
TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thank you.

```
    import pandas_datareader as web
    import datetime as dt

    ticker = "NLY"
    source = "yahoo"
    start = dt.datetime(2022, 12, 1)
    end = dt.datetime.now()

    df = web.DataReader(ticker, source, start, end)
    print(df)
```

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/952

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["TypeError: string indices must be integers" when getting data of a stock from Yahoo Finance using Pandas Datareader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832296/typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-when-getting-data-of-a-stock-from-y)

Answer (score 0):

i think it is due to dictionary update by yahoo- it would require Datareader to update its library.