# typeerror: string indices must be integer pandas datareader

Tags: python, string, typeerror, datareader

I want to print out SPY's stock data however it keeps shows typeerror: string indices must be integer

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web

spy = web.get_data_yahoo('SPY',start='2022-12-23',end='2022-10-24')

print(spy)
```

Comment: web.get_data_yahoo('SPY', start='2022-10-24', end='2022-12-23')

Comment: This was already asked here [why am I getting a "TypeError: String indices Must be integer" Message when trying to access Yahoo Finance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74862453/6045800) and it seems to be [a known issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/952)

Comment: @tomerar thank you! but it says the start date can't be earlier than the end date

Comment: Swap "start" and "end".

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["TypeError: string indices must be integers" when getting data of a stock from Yahoo Finance using Pandas Datareader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832296/typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-when-getting-data-of-a-stock-from-y)

Answer (score 21):

I would solve for this way:

```
import pandas
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance as yfin


yfin.pdr_override()

spy = pdr.get_data_yahoo('SPY', start='2022-10-24', end='2022-12-23')

print(spy)
```

I think it will work.

Comment: But what is the underlying issue?

Comment: The above isn't working 1 month later

Comment: That is interesting, for me it still works.

Comment: start and end are invalid in the statement given: SPY: Invalid input - start date cannot be after end date. startDate = 1671771600, endDate = 1666584000 
spy = pdr.get_data_yahoo('SPY',start='2022-10-23',end='2022-12-24')
 works

Comment: I'm not sure if pdr is deprecated, or what the implications of "override()" on it with yfin is.

But I just simply used yfinance `.download()
` instead to generate the same dataframe.

`import yfinance as yf`
`SPY = yf.download('SPY', start='1995-1-1')`

Comment: didnt work for me as well.