# Why I receive a Type Error on Python yahoo finance?

Tags: python, typeerror, yahoo-finance

I have a code used in the past with no problem. Now I use this:

```
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
si.get_income_statement('aapl')
```

and get this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\xxxxxx Cell 4 in <module>
      1 import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
----> 2 si.get_income_statement('aapl')

File c:\xxxxx\yahoo_fin\stock_info.py:422, in get_income_statement(ticker, yearly)
    419 json_info = _parse_json(income_site)
    421 if yearly:
--> 422     temp = json_info["incomeStatementHistory"]["incomeStatementHistory"]
    423 else:
    424     temp = json_info["incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly"]["incomeStatementHistory"]

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: This looks like an yahoo_fin issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["TypeError: string indices must be integers" when getting data of a stock from Yahoo Finance using Pandas Datareader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832296/typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-when-getting-data-of-a-stock-from-y)

Answer (score 1):

The API for Yahoo has changed and this is an issue with the package itself and has depracated, so that is why it is not working. You can refer to [this](https://github.com/atreadw1492/yahoo_fin/issues/94) for a better understanding of the issue

You can use a better package [yfinance](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance), which is currently being constantly updated.