# Getting stock history from Yahoo Finance or YahooFinancials using Yahoo_fin

Tags: python, stock, yahoo-finance

I am using yahoo_fin open python package where it has stock listings already within their library so I don't have to do any extra work manually typing it in. So I found a few YouTube clips and a few codes from this website as well. It used to work with yahoo_financials but now it doesn't and it was very quick. I really need help for a project that is due within a week or less.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
from yahoo_fin import *
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr


# deleting stock symbols/tickers within the nasdaq listing
nasdaq = pd.DataFrame(si.tickers_nasdaq())
sym = set( symbol for symbol in nasdaq[0].values.tolist() )

# deleting the inactive tickers by suffix
my_list = ['W', 'R', 'P', 'Q']

# variable for tickers to be saved and disgarded
del_set = set()
sav_set = set()

# loop to id the suffix and disgard
for symbol in sym:
if len(symbol) > 4 and symbol[-1] in my_list:
    del_set.add(symbol)
else:
    sav_set.add(symbol)

yf.pdr_override()

# financial = YahooFinancials(sav_set)

# creating date variables going back one month to today's date
begin = (dt.datetime.today() - dt.timedelta(30)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
stop = dt.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

       # # retrieving historical data through Yahoo Financials
       # data = financial.get_historical_price_data(begin, stop, 'daily')

# # creating a database for Adjusted Close on every ticker symbol
# prices = pd.DataFrame({
#     a: {x['formatted_date']: x['adjclose'] for x in data[a]['prices']} for a in assets
# })

# # naming index column
# prices.index.name = 'Date'

# creating the dataframe for the adjusted close
prices = pd.DataFrame()
for stock in sav_set:
    prices[stock] = yf.download(stock, start = begin, end = stop)['Adj Close']

# displaying the dataframe
prices

When I use YahooFinancials:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoofinancials\__init__.py in _create_dict_ent(self, up_ticker,         statement_type, tech_type, report_name, hist_obj)
    415             try:
--> 416                 cleaned_re_data = self._recursive_api_request(hist_obj, up_ticker)
    417             except KeyError:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoofinancials\__init__.py in _recursive_api_request(self,   hist_obj, up_ticker, i)
 384         api_url = self._build_api_url(hist_obj, up_ticker)
--> 385         re_data = self._clean_api_data(api_url)
 386         cleaned_re_data = self._clean_historical_data(re_data)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoofinancials\__init__.py in _clean_api_data(self, api_url)
358             ret_obj.update({'timeZone': tz_sub_dict})
--> 359             timestamp_list = result['timestamp']
360             high_price_list = result['indicators']['quote'][0]['high']

KeyError: 'timestamp'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_27256\2265982296.py in <module>
 10 
 11 # retrieving historical data through Yahoo Financials
---> 12 data = financial.get_historical_price_data(begin, stop, 'daily')
 13 
 14 # creating a database for Adjusted Close on every ticker symbol

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoofinancials\__init__.py in get_historical_price_data(self, start_date, end_date, time_interval)
645         end = self.format_date(end_date)
646         hist_obj = {'start': start, 'end': end, 'interval': interval_code}
--> 647         return self.get_stock_data('history', hist_obj=hist_obj)
648 
649     # Private Method for Functions needing stock_price_data

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoofinancials\__init__.py in get_stock_data(self, statement_type, tech_type, report_name, hist_obj)
479             for tick in self.ticker:
480                 try:
--> 481                     dict_ent = self._create_dict_ent(tick, statement_type, tech_type, report_name, hist_obj)
482                     data.update(dict_ent)
483                 except ManagedException:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoofinancials\__init__.py in _create_dict_ent(self, up_ticker, statement_type, tech_type, report_name, hist_obj)
417             except KeyError:
418                 try:
--> 419                     re_data = self._scrape_data(YAHOO_URL, tech_type, statement_type)
420                     cleaned_re_data = self._clean_historical_data(re_data)
421                 except KeyError:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoofinancials\__init__.py in _scrape_data(self, url, tech_type, statement_type)
169             stores = data["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["QuoteSummaryStore"][tech_type]
170         else:
--> 171             stores = data["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
172         return stores
173 

TypeError: string indices must be integers


When I use YFinance:

PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
prices[stock] = yf.download(stock, start = begin, end = stop)['Adj Close']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["TypeError: string indices must be integers" when getting data of a stock from Yahoo Finance using Pandas Datareader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832296/typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-when-getting-data-of-a-stock-from-y)

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo made a change, hopefully pandas developers will have a fix soon

If you look at the html source code : https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MCD/history?p=MCD

you'll find around line 244 :
root.App.main = { }

unfortunately the json string is too large to put here.

Bottom line : the value for 'stores' key is no longer a dict but a string.

A really long encrypted/encoded string.

It's puking on the string['HistoricalPriceStore']

I am submitting ticket/issue pandas.