# Hidden Markov Model Machine Learning

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I am currently trying to get data from  yfinance using pandas, This is my code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from pyhhmm.gaussian import GaussianHMM
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


start_date = "2017-01-01"
end_date = "2023-01-04"
symbol = "SPY"
data = DataReader(name=symbol, data_source= "yahoo", start=start_date, end=end_date)
data
```

I already installed all packages using pip but it throws an error and exception when i get to calling the data variable.

I would really appreciate any help.

These are the errors thrown:

```js
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <cell line: 8>()
      6 api = ""
      7 session = ""
----> 8 data = DataReader(name=symbol, data_source= "yahoo", start=start_date, end=end_date)
      9 data.head()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:207, in deprecate_kwarg.<locals>._deprecate_kwarg.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    205     else:
    206         kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 207 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py:370, in DataReader(name, data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause, session, api_key)
    367     raise NotImplementedError(msg)
    369 if data_source == "yahoo":
--> 370     return YahooDailyReader(
    371         symbols=name,
    372         start=start,
    373         end=end,
    374         adjust_price=False,
    375         chunksize=25,
    376         retry_count=retry_count,
    377         pause=pause,
    378         session=session,
    379     ).read()
    381 elif data_source == "iex":
    382     return IEXDailyReader(
    383         symbols=name,
    384         start=start,
   (...)
    390         session=session,
    391     ).read()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py:253, in _DailyBaseReader.read(self)
    251 # If a single symbol, (e.g., 'GOOG')
    252 if isinstance(self.symbols, (string_types, int)):
--> 253     df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
    254 # Or multiple symbols, (e.g., ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'])
    255 elif isinstance(self.symbols, DataFrame):

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py:153, in YahooDailyReader._read_one_data(self, url, params)
    151 try:
    152     j = json.loads(re.search(ptrn, resp.text, re.DOTALL).group(1))
--> 153     data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
    154 except KeyError:
    155     msg = "No data fetched for symbol {} using {}"

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Can you please add the error that you are getting into your question?

Comment: I added the error to my code above. Thank you

Comment: This is a problem with the way Yahoo stores its information, which is now encrypted and can no longer be read by pandas_datareader. See https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/956 and the requested fix https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/pull/953.

Comment: Thank you kind dev. 

I was able to fix it

Comment: @CitronW can you share how you fix it?

Comment: It looks like Yahoo have changed the encrypted data format again (in the last few days) and now even the PR https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/pull/953 does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["TypeError: string indices must be integers" when getting data of a stock from Yahoo Finance using Pandas Datareader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832296/typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-when-getting-data-of-a-stock-from-y)

Answer (score 0):

```
def wordInSymbs(str):
    list = []
    for i in range(len(str)):
        list.append(str[i])
    return list

n = int(input())
parts = []
numbers = []
listOfCounts = [0]
for i in range(n):
    parts.append(wordInSymbs(input()))
m = int(input())
listOfCounts = [0]*m
for i in range(m):
    numbers.append(wordInSymbs(input()))
    for j in range(len(parts)):
        if set(parts[j]) <= set(numbers[i]):
            listOfCounts[i] += 1
for i in range(m):
    if listOfCounts[i] == max(listOfCounts):
        print(''.join(numbers[i]))
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation of how that code helps solve that question? That should make it a lot easier to understand for the OP and future readers.

Answer (score 0):

```
 n = int(input())
    str = ''
    for i in range(n):
        str += 'r, y, g'
        if (i + 1) != n:
            str += ', y, '
    print(str.count('r'), str.count('y'))
```

Comment: a = int(input())
b = int(input())

while a < b:
    if len(str(a)) == 4:
        for i in range(10):
            if str(a).count(str(i)) == 3:
                print(a)
    a += 1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

'cut'

```
from sys import stdin


option = input()
list = []
for line in stdin:
    if line.rstrip() == 'Exit':
        break
    newline = line.split()
    list.append(newline)

if option[:-1] == '-c':
    s = int(option[-1])-1
    for i in range(len(list)):
        print(list[i][s])
else:
    for i in range(len(list)):
        print('\t'.join(list[i]), end='\n')
```

Comment: Please add an explanation! This helps people understand how your answer solves the questions.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, there was a change to how Yahoo Finance shared there historical data (it became encrypted), which [broke](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/pull/953) how the `panda_datareader` package tried accessing this data. This caused the problem that the OP was seeing. This change has been fixed in this [Pull Request](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/pull/953), although it has yet to be merged and released as a new version of `pandas_datareader`. For now, the a version with the fix can be used and installed directly with:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/hellc/pandas-datareader.git@87dda3f297df8f4b3253c6f2d5006b5ac43a9150
```