# Python YFinance - Earnings Calendar no longer works

Tags: python, yfinance

I am trying to get the next earnings date using python. Up until now, I've been using:

```
obj = yf.Ticker('TSLA')
cal = obj.calendar
next_earnings_date = cal.iloc[0][0]
```

I think the API has recently broken. I have also tried:

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import pandas as pd
 
df = web.DataReader('AAPL', data_source='yahoo', start='2011-01-01', end='2021-01-12')
df.head()

import yfinance as yf
aapl = yf.Ticker("AAPL")
print(aapl.earnings)
```

I tried this one also:

```
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si

for ticker_symbol in ['IMGN', 'DIDI']:
    print('Symbol:', ticker_symbol)
    try:
        tickerEarnings = si.get_next_earnings_date(ticker_symbol)
        print('Earnings:', tickerEarnings)
    except Exception as ex:
        print('[Exception]', ex)
        print('Earnings: skiping this symbol')import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si

    for ticker_symbol in ['IMGN', 'DIDI']:
        print('Symbol:', ticker_symbol)
        try:
            tickerEarnings = si.get_next_earnings_date(ticker_symbol)
            print('Earnings:', tickerEarnings)
        except Exception as ex:
            print('[Exception]', ex)
            print('Earnings: skiping this symbol')
```

The reason I think the API is broken is because I'm getting

```
data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers in some of the things that I have tried.
```

Comment: Could you please share the version you are using? Could not reproduce using the latest yfinance installation. Could be fixed with https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/pull/1297.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/75161858/1862861

Answer (score 2):

I have been having the same issue over the last 2 days. Here's my code to obtain the calendar:

```
import yfinance as yf
stock = yf.Ticker("NFLX")
stock.calendar
```

And here's the error i've been getting:

> Exception: Yahoo has again changed data format, yfinance now unsure which key(s) is for decryption: '8859304c7f55'-><class 'str'>

Until a solution is provided, you can try the code below:

```
ES = stock.get_earnings_dates()
ES.head()
```

Hope it helps.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow3Fx.png)

Comment: I'm getting AttributeError: 'Ticker' object has no attribute 'get_earnings_dates'

Comment: In that case, i would suggest checking the version: $pip install --upgrade yfinance