# YFNotImplementedError: Have not implemented fetching 'calendar' from Yahoo API

Tags: python, yfinance

Unable to get calendar via `yfinance`:

```
t = yf.Ticker('GOOGL')
t.calendar
```

Triggers:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
YFNotImplementedError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 2
      1 t = yf.Ticker('GOOGL')
----> 2 t.calendar

File ~/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/yfinance/ticker.py:142, in Ticker.calendar(self)
    140 @property
    141 def calendar(self) -> _pd.DataFrame:
--> 142     return self.get_calendar()

File ~/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/yfinance/base.py:1471, in TickerBase.get_calendar(self, proxy, as_dict)
   1469 def get_calendar(self, proxy=None, as_dict=False):
   1470     self._quote.proxy = proxy
-> 1471     data = self._quote.calendar
   1472     if as_dict:
   1473         return data.to_dict()

File ~/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/yfinance/scrapers/quote.py:583, in Quote.calendar(self)
    580 @property
    581 def calendar(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
    582     if self._calendar is None:
--> 583         raise YFNotImplementedError('calendar')
    584     return self._calendar

YFNotImplementedError: Have not implemented fetching 'calendar' from Yahoo API
```

System:

- Ubuntu 23.04
- Python 3.11.2
- yfinance 0.2.21

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75223206/python-yfinance-earnings-calendar-no-longer-works