# Error "string indices must be integer" when selecting yahoo finance stock data with "start" and "end" dates

Tags: python, typeerror, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I want to create a simple script that pulls stock data from yahoo finance with pandas_datareader package:

```
from pandas_datareader import data

stocks = data.DataReader('MSFT', 'yahoo', start='2020-01-14', end='2023-01-14')
```

but the code gets me "string indices must be integers" TypeError message

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 3
      1 from pandas_datareader import data
----> 3 stocks = data.DataReader('MSFT', 'yahoo', start='2020-01-14', end='2023-01-14')

File c:\Users\der_L\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:211, in deprecate_kwarg.<locals>._deprecate_kwarg.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    209     else:
    210         kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 211 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File c:\Users\der_L\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py:379, in DataReader(name, data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause, session, api_key)
    367     raise NotImplementedError(msg)
    369 if data_source == "yahoo":
    370     return YahooDailyReader(
    371         symbols=name,
    372         start=start,
    373         end=end,
    374         adjust_price=False,
    375         chunksize=25,
    376         retry_count=retry_count,
    377         pause=pause,
    378         session=session,
--> 379     ).read()
    381 elif data_source == "iex":
...
--> 153     data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
    154 except KeyError:
    155     msg = "No data fetched for symbol {} using {}"

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The script is almost the same as many seen on the web but I can't understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: If it's *almost* the same you might be able to figure out what causes the problem by examining what the difference is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["TypeError: string indices must be integers" when getting data of a stock from Yahoo Finance using Pandas Datareader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832296/typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-when-getting-data-of-a-stock-from-y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like currently there is a change that is not updated on pandas-datareader yet. The bug report can be found [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/952). As a workaround you can use yfinance package as shown below. For this to work you should install yfinance package with `pip install yfinance`.

Then, below modified code should set everything going.

```py
from pandas_datareader import data
import yfinance as yfin

yfin.pdr_override()

stocks = data.get_data_yahoo('MSFT', start='2020-01-14', end='2023-01-14')
```

Comment: speaking of yfinance I've noticed that yfin.Ticker("MSFT").info throws the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You are using strings for the start and end dates.  Use:

```
import datetime  
  
start_date = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 14)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 14)
```

Then use these in the DataReader call