# TypeError: string indices must be integers in the time of downloading stock data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, yahoo-finance, yfinance

Previously, this same code was running perfectly. However, I encountered this error recently "TypeError: string indices must be integers".

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

start=datetime.datetime(2015,6,1)
end=datetime.datetime(2022,6,30)

sbin=web.DataReader('SBIN.BO','yahoo',start,end)
tatamotors=web.DataReader('TATAMOTORS.BO','yahoo',start,end)
reliance=web.DataReader('RELIANCE.BO','yahoo',start,end)
```

I have tried this code by considering other stock aslo. But same result obtained. After running the above code, the error occured as follows:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 sbin=web.DataReader('SBIN.BO','yahoo',start,end)
      2 tatamotors=web.DataReader('TATAMOTORS.BO','yahoo',start,end)
      3 reliance=web.DataReader('RELIANCE.BO','yahoo',start,end)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:207, in deprecate_kwarg.<locals>._deprecate_kwarg.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    205     else:
    206         kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 207 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py:370, in DataReader(name, data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause, session, api_key)
    367     raise NotImplementedError(msg)
    369 if data_source == "yahoo":
--> 370     return YahooDailyReader(
    371         symbols=name,
    372         start=start,
    373         end=end,
    374         adjust_price=False,
    375         chunksize=25,
    376         retry_count=retry_count,
    377         pause=pause,
    378         session=session,
    379     ).read()
    381 elif data_source == "iex":
    382     return IEXDailyReader(
    383         symbols=name,
    384         start=start,
   (...)
    390         session=session,
    391     ).read()

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py:253, in _DailyBaseReader.read(self)
    251 # If a single symbol, (e.g., 'GOOG')
    252 if isinstance(self.symbols, (string_types, int)):
--> 253     df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
    254 # Or multiple symbols, (e.g., ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'])
    255 elif isinstance(self.symbols, DataFrame):

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py:153, in YahooDailyReader._read_one_data(self, url, params)
    151 try:
    152     j = json.loads(re.search(ptrn, resp.text, re.DOTALL).group(1))
--> 153     data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
    154 except KeyError:
    155     msg = "No data fetched for symbol {} using {}"

TypeError: string indices must be integers.
```

Please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["TypeError: string indices must be integers" when getting data of a stock from Yahoo Finance using Pandas Datareader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832296/typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-when-getting-data-of-a-stock-from-y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a long-standing [gh-issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/952) that discusses your problem. As the corresponding [PR](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/pull/953) hasn't been merged as of today, I would recommend to use the [`yfinance`](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/) override instead:

```py
import datetime

import pandas_datareader.data as web
import yfinance as yf

yf.pdr_override()

start=datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 1)
end=datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 30)

sbin = web.DataReader('SBIN.BO', start, end)
tatamotors = web.DataReader('TATAMOTORS.BO', start, end)
reliance = web.DataReader('RELIANCE.BO', start, end)
```

**Output for SBIN:**

```
    Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume
Date                        
2015-06-01 00:00:00+05:30   279.000000  281.950012  277.600006  278.149994  265.453278  1331528
2015-06-02 00:00:00+05:30   278.500000  279.500000  265.500000  266.250000  254.096466  3382530
2015-06-03 00:00:00+05:30   267.149994  268.000000  255.100006  257.549988  245.793579  2706069
```