# Problem with getting data from Yahoo finance with python

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I am trying to get data from Yahoo finance but keep getting the same error that says:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-3fd0d552ddbc> in <module>
      6 enddate = dt.datetime.now()
      7 
----> 8 data = web.get_data_yahoo(y_symbols, start=startdate, end=enddate)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py in _read_one_data(self, url, params)
    151         try:
    152             j = json.loads(re.search(ptrn, resp.text, re.DOTALL).group(1))
--> 153             data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
    154         except KeyError:
    155             msg = "No data fetched for symbol {} using {}"

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The code I am using is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime as dt

import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()

currency = 'BTC'
against_currency='USD'
y_symbols = [currency,against_currency]

startdate = dt.datetime(2016,1,1)
enddate = dt.datetime.now()

data = web.get_data_yahoo(y_symbols, start=startdate, end=enddate)
```

I tried updating the packages and many other solutions i found but nothing worked.

Comment: Can't you use yfinance directly ? Using debugger, it seems that the answer returned in variable j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]  is a string.  So the problem, if any, is in the way pandas_datareader handles the Yahoo's answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["TypeError: string indices must be integers" when getting data of a stock from Yahoo Finance using Pandas Datareader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832296/typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-when-getting-data-of-a-stock-from-y)