# How to use the pandas_datareader library?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I imported this library but it's not giving error

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import datetime as dt

start_date = dt.datetime(2021, 1, 1)
end_date = dt.datetime(2021, 12, 31)

df = pdr.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', start=start_date, end=end_date)
print(df.head())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["TypeError: string indices must be integers" when getting data of a stock from Yahoo Finance using Pandas Datareader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832296/typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-when-getting-data-of-a-stock-from-y)

Answer (score 0):

You can import `yfinance`:

```
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()
```

Than just use your code. It works for me.