# Why am I getting TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

Tags: pandas, yahoo-finance

Below is the code. Whenever I try to run this it says type error: string indices must be integers, #not "str"

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr

start = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days = 365*3)
end = dt.datetime.now()

stocks = ['VOO', 'QQQ']

df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stocks, start, end)
df.head()
```

I am trying to get data from yahoo finance on VOO and QQQ stock price from the last three years to today. I am getting a large error code that ends with string indices must be integers, not 'str'

Comment: Please show the entire traceback.  Also note that Yahoo regularly changes their website and API, which breaks libraries like this.

Comment: Most likely, you're using your library incorrectly. Double check you're passing valid parameters. If this is the case, then the full traceback will be needed to see whether this could be a bug.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832296/typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-when-getting-data-of-a-stock-from-y

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["TypeError: string indices must be integers" when getting data of a stock from Yahoo Finance using Pandas Datareader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832296/typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-when-getting-data-of-a-stock-from-y)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `yfinance` as replacement of `pandas_datareader`:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

start = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days = 365*3)
end = dt.datetime.now()

stocks = ['VOO', 'QQQ']

df = yf.download(stocks, start, end)
df.head()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
             Adj Close                   Close                    High  ...         Low        Open                Volume         
                   QQQ         VOO         QQQ         VOO         QQQ  ...         VOO         QQQ         VOO       QQQ      VOO
Date                                                                    ...                                                       
2020-12-23  302.548248  322.488678  308.200012  337.809998  310.179993  ...  337.690002  309.809998  338.540009  21201300  3682200
2020-12-24  303.883270  323.777466  309.559998  339.160004  310.019989  ...  337.769989  308.470001  338.369995  16785000  1447500
2020-12-28  306.946106  326.593658  312.679993  342.109985  313.170013  ...  341.089996  312.250000  341.739990  22497700  2798800
2020-12-29  307.220886  325.906342  312.959991  341.390015  314.690002  ...  340.869995  314.049988  343.630005  25871900  2555500
2020-12-30  307.230774  326.345490  312.970001  341.850006  314.489990  ...  341.570007  314.160004  342.279999  18138100  2009100
...                ...         ...         ...         ...         ...  ...         ...         ...         ...       ...      ...
2023-12-18  407.079987  433.749908  407.079987  435.540009  407.989990  ...  434.450012  404.929993  434.640015  46610000  4280500
2023-12-19  409.160004  436.389008  409.160004  438.190002  409.279999  ...  435.950012  407.540009  436.040009  35711900  4061500
2023-12-20  403.079987  430.089996  403.079987  430.089996  410.470001  ...  429.899994  408.350006  435.510010  54042400  5783200
2023-12-21  407.769989  434.279999  407.769989  434.279999  408.140015  ...  430.859985  407.059998  433.130005  45568900  4621600
2023-12-22  408.380005  435.290009  408.380005  435.290009  409.970001  ...  433.480011  409.000000  435.459991  34292400  4035200

[755 rows x 12 columns]
```