# string indices must be integers - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an error code : Financial Data Analysis with Python

CODE

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from pandas_datareader import data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns 
import plotly.express as px

azul_df = data.DataReader(name='AZUL4.SA', data_source='yahoo',start='2019-01-01', end='2019-12-12')
print(azul_df)
```

TERMINAL

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python-financas\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    azul_df = data.DataReader(name='AZUL4.SA', data_source='yahoo',start='2019-01-01', end='2019-12-12')
  File "D:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 213, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 379, in DataReader
    ).read()
  File "D:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 253, in read
    df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
  File "D:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py", line 153, in _read_one_data
    data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
PS D:\python-financas> & D:/Python/Python310/python.exe d:/python-financas/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python-financas\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    azul_df = data.DataReader(name='AZUL4.SA', data_source='yahoo',start='2019-01-01', end='2019-12-12') 
  File "D:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 213, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 379, in DataReader        
    ).read()
  File "D:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 253, in read
    df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
  File "D:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py", line 153, in _read_one_data
    data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Receive information from AZUL4.SA

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["TypeError: string indices must be integers" when getting data of a stock from Yahoo Finance using Pandas Datareader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832296/typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-when-getting-data-of-a-stock-from-y)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `pandas_data` to get historical data from yahoo. Install the `yfinance` package:

```
#!pip install yfinance
import yfinance as yf

azul_df = yf.download('AZUL4.SA', start='2019-01-01', end='2019-12-12')
```

Output:

```
>>> azul_df
                 Open       High        Low      Close  Adj Close   Volume
Date                                                                      
2019-01-02  35.970001  36.549999  35.450001  36.330002  36.330002  2795000
2019-01-03  36.189999  37.599998  35.709999  36.369999  36.369999  1636900
2019-01-04  36.480000  36.630001  35.799999  36.250000  36.250000  1056400
2019-01-07  36.160000  36.470001  34.910000  35.299999  35.299999  1215300
2019-01-08  35.590000  35.939999  34.400002  34.720001  34.720001  1299600
...               ...        ...        ...        ...        ...      ...
2019-12-05  53.189999  54.000000  52.959999  53.410000  53.410000  1488800
2019-12-06  53.500000  54.830002  52.759998  54.700001  54.700001  4114500
2019-12-09  54.689999  55.400002  54.080002  54.709999  54.709999  2013100
2019-12-10  54.470001  54.470001  52.330002  53.599998  53.599998  3990600
2019-12-11  53.990002  54.860001  53.630001  54.639999  54.639999  2650400

[237 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Note: I already answered to this question but I can't find it!