# Error from pulling data from Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I am just starting to code python on Jupyter and I can't seem to solve this problem.
I was trying to import data from Yahoo Finance but it doesn't let me. I don't know if I have to install a new version of Pandas, because I already did. Maybe it has something to do with the function being old, I don't know.

Here's the code and the message of error:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from pandas_datareader import data as wb

PG = wb.DataReader('Pg', data_source='yahoo', start='1995-1-1')
```

Error from the line of code above:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 PG = wb.DataReader('Pg', data_source='yahoo', start='1995-1-1')

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:213, in deprecate_kwarg.<locals>._deprecate_kwarg.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    211         raise TypeError(msg)
    212     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 213 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py:379, in DataReader(name, data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause, session, api_key)
    367     raise NotImplementedError(msg)
    369 if data_source == "yahoo":
    370     return YahooDailyReader(
    371         symbols=name,
    372         start=start,
    373         end=end,
    374         adjust_price=False,
    375         chunksize=25,
    376         retry_count=retry_count,
    377         pause=pause,
    378         session=session,
--> 379     ).read()
    381 elif data_source == "iex":
    382     return IEXDailyReader(
    383         symbols=name,
    384         start=start,
   (...)
    390         session=session,
    391     ).read()

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py:253, in _DailyBaseReader.read(self)
    251 # If a single symbol, (e.g., 'GOOG')
    252 if isinstance(self.symbols, (string_types, int)):
--> 253     df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
    254 # Or multiple symbols, (e.g., ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'])
    255 elif isinstance(self.symbols, DataFrame):

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py:153, in YahooDailyReader._read_one_data(self, url, params)
    151 try:
    152     j = json.loads(re.search(ptrn, resp.text, re.DOTALL).group(1))
--> 153     data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
    154 except KeyError:
    155     msg = "No data fetched for symbol {} using {}"

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Instead of `start='1995-1-1'`, try `start='1995-01-01'`.

Comment: Welcome. Have you searched for previous reports of the same error? There seems to exist a few. Does this answer your question? ["TypeError: string indices must be integers" when getting data of a stock from Yahoo Finance using Pandas Datareader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832296/typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-when-getting-data-of-a-stock-from-y)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking i use the `yfinance` module for yahoo finance, which can be found here:  https://pypi.org/project/yfinance

I find the API more convenient.

here is some boiler plate that i start with:

```py
import yfinance as yf
import pprint


def main():
    yhoo_object = yf.Ticker("MSFT")
    print(yhoo_object.dividends)
    pprint.pp(yhoo_object.info['longName'])
    print('the sum of the dividends are: ', sum(yhoo_object.dividends))
    last_price = round(yhoo_object.history(period='1m')['Close'][0] , 1)
    print('the last price: ', last_price)
    print(type(last_price))

    tickers = yf.Tickers('msft aapl goog')
    print(tickers.tickers)

    # for i in tickers.tickers:
    #     last_price = round(i.history(period='1m')['Close'][0] , 1)
    #     print(f'the mast price for {i} is {last_price} ')
    #     pass
    # return




def get_data_from_yhoo(yhoo_object):
    '''
    example of things that the user can get back from yahoo.

    A lot of the values return type is pandas data series.

    inputs:
        yhoo_object (yfinance.ticker.Ticker): 

    '''

    # get stock info
    yhoo_object.info

    # get historical market data
    hist = yhoo_object.history(period="max")

    # show actions (dividends, splits)
    yhoo_object.actions

    # show dividends
    yhoo_object.dividends

    # show splits
    yhoo_object.splits

    # show financials
    yhoo_object.financials
    yhoo_object.quarterly_financials

    # show major holders
    yhoo_object.major_holders

    # show institutional holders
    yhoo_object.institutional_holders

    # show balance sheet
    yhoo_object.balance_sheet
    yhoo_object.quarterly_balance_sheet

    # show cashflow
    yhoo_object.cashflow
    yhoo_object.quarterly_cashflow

    # show earnings
    yhoo_object.earnings
    yhoo_object.quarterly_earnings

    # show sustainability
    yhoo_object.sustainability

    # show analysts recommendations
    yhoo_object.recommendations

    # show next event (earnings, etc)
    yhoo_object.calendar

    # show ISIN code - *experimental*
    # ISIN = International Securities Identification Number
    yhoo_object.isin

    # show options expirations
    yhoo_object.options

    # get option chain for specific expiration
    # opt = yhoo_object.option_chain('YYYY-MM-DD')
    # data available via: opt.calls, opt.puts



if __name__=='__main__':
    ''' This is executed when run from the command line '''
    main()
```

But there is a whole bunch of other stuff that one can do.